# Which cases SuperNotCalledException is thrown

Tags: android, exception

When overriding methods in Android apps, many a times we need to call through to the super method.

In some cases, like in a fragment's `onActivityCreated()` method, a `SuperNotCalledException` will be thrown if super is not called. In other cases, like in an activity's `onCreateOptionsMenu()` method, although the offical documentation(http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html) shows sample code that calls the super method, in practice it is not really required and an Exception will not be thrown.

So my question is if there is any rule of thumb i can use to guess when a call to super might be required.

Comment: First rule of thumb: check the documentation of the method.

Comment: Second rule of thumb: check the sources of the method if you are not sure.

Comment: The documentation does not really help. For example http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onActivityCreated(android.os.Bundle) does not say to call super.

Comment: Here's to answer the question in the title: http://androidxref.com/4.4.2_r2/search?q=supernotcalledexception&project=frameworks

Comment: @laalto that's really interesting. That pretty much answers my question. If you can post that as an answer, i can accept it. It would have helped even more if androidxref listed the function name as well so that i do not have to click on every search result to find out which function it is in.

Comment: This exception occurs when you forget to call `super.myMethod();` in an overridden method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, activity and fragment lifecycle callbacks that modify the object's state must call the parent implementation. Callbacks that don't modify the object state but just return an object or modify one passed in as an argument (such as the `Menu` passed to `onCreateOptionsMenu()`) don't require calling the parent implementation. The parent just provides a useful default implementation (often empty) but it may be completely overridden.

To learn where `SuperNotCalledException` is thrown exactly, [grep the source](http://androidxref.com/4.4.2_r2/search?q=supernotcalledexception&project=frameworks).

`SuperNotCalledException` problems are also easy to reproduce and fix. Just remember to test your app.